# Copy content from WYSIWYG editor to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, quill

I try to copy the content from a WYSIWYG-Editor (What you see is what you get), to a textarea and It needs to be structured. I am using Quill https://www.quilljs.com/docs/quickstart

I added a textarea, the content from the Editor is pasted into it, on click at the button `Edit HTML`.

```
$("#editHTML").click(function() {
   var content = $("#editor .ql-editor").html();
   $("#htmlEditForm").html(content);
});
```

It works, but as you can see it is not structured at all. Everything is in one line:

[image]

I need it like this:

```
<p>FOO</p>
<p>BAR</p>
<p class="ql-align-center"><span style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">I am centered</span></p>
```

I need it to be in a textarea, because I want to use it as HTML editor. Later on I will add another button which pastes the html code back into the WYSIWYG-editor.

The goal is, to give advanced users the possibilty to edit the HTML.

I am not sure how I can do this, I was thinking of replacing any closing tags with this: e.g. `</p>` -> `</p>\n` but it just outputs `</p>\n` in the textarea instead of creating a new line.

Is this even possible?

UPDATE:

I tried to use `getContents` as suggested:

```
var toolbarOptions = [
  ['image'],
  [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
  [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
  [{ 'align': [] }],
  ['blockquote', 'code-block'],


  [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
  [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
  [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction
  [{ 'font': [ 'arial', 'Monotype Corsiva', 'fantasy', 'serif' ] }],


  ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
];

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow',
  modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
  }
});

$("#editHTML").click(function() {
    $("#htmlEditForm").html(quill.getContents());
});
```

But the textarea stays empty.

`quill.getContents()` does just return an object:

[image]

Comment: "WYSIWYG" then why change what you get?

Comment: I want to give users the possibilty to edit the HTML, for advanced users.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: I am using `quill` https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/

Comment: Use `getContents` in that api instead of `html()` and see if it is formatted

Comment: I tried it and I get `getContents is not a function`

Comment: Why don't you use editor that works without textarea or input.  jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/   I just googled that. 2c

Comment: Not using api correctly then

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, I tried it, see my updated question. But the textarea stays empty.

Comment: Lots of editors that do format the source...CKeditor & tinyMce are 2 off top of my head

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Quill is not meant to do this. **Quill uses it's own document model called [Parchment](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/)**. It tracks everything that changes in the editor so that it can understand it's contents and make changes, but it has some limits on what can be added. For example, you can't add an element that doesn't match an existing blot/format.

If someone were to edit the HTML arbitrarily and add a div for example, the editor's document model would no longer match it's contents. When switching back to the wysiwyg view, some functions wouldn't work until it tries to recreate it's document model and messes up the changes made in the HTML view.

**Edit**

Also, for the original problem of how to format the HTML with new lines and indention, what your seeing is how it's formatted. The editor is not breaking to new lines for each block element or adding indentation for nesting as someone would when they're writing code.

If you want it to be formatted in some way, you'd have to do it manually. Either by parsing the `getContents()` output or by writing or finding a script that can format HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your text area with Ace Editor (https://ace.c9.io/) which allows code editing features.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting .click event use the built-in quill mechanism 'text-change' ... also to get the HTML of the rich text editor all in one go use .container.childNodes[0].innerHTML

```
quill.on('text-change', function (delta, oldDelta, source) {
  // your code here e.g.
  $("#htmlEditForm").html(quill.container.childNodes[0].innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Text area is not capable of showing you the formats of rich text editors. A simple solution can be strip all tags if you do not want the tags in text area. Or if you want tags like bold, italic etc you have to use WYSIWYG editor. You can disable all tools of the editor and it would be looking like a textarea.

Comment: I need the textarea as HTML editor, so I need to keep all the tags.

Comment: So simply use the WYSIWYG editor and disable all of its tools so that you can only see a box without tools.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work, It does convert it to normal html without tags

Comment: Which WYSIWYG are you using ?

Comment: 'var toolbarOptions = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'];

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  }
});
'

Comment: `var toolbarOptions = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'];

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  }
});
` Found this you can configure the tools